# On selection merge boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-selectable

I'm trying to develop a small page that has the following functionality:

- there shoud have 10 row and 3 boxes in each row.
- if i select 2 or more boxes or drag a box it should be merged.

for example if the following is my first screen 
[image]
then i am selecting two boxes then the following is the result 
[image]

Please see [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nisham/fmusV/19/)

here it works only first time.i want to save state,and when i click `close` button it should roll back to previous states.

please help me.

Comment: take a look at last code. You should pay me! (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that you're using merge function that I provide to you, well.

As I tell you, code is only to explain the general approach to follow.

Remember also to call this function to make new element droppable:

```
var modifyAsDroppable = function(target) {
    var what = "<div class=\"handle ui-selectee\"><span class=\"ui-icon ui-icon-carat-2-n-s ui-selectee\"></span></div>";
    target.prepend(what);
}
```

In **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/fmusV/26/)** version I divide each task in different function, so *merge()* become:

```
var merge = function() {
    /* contains: top left bottom right */
    var properties = calculateSize();
    var $merged = createNewDiv();
    insert($merged, searchWhereInsert(properties));
    modifyAsDroppable($merged);
    setSize($merged, properties);
    removeMerged();
}
```

If you want that it works not only first time, you have to make working the way on how you fullfill the **selected** array.

## UPDATE

In **[this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fmusV/27/)** I've fixed "one-time-working" and now works always. There was a bug on selected array creation, now is:

```
if(index >= 0) {
  selected.push(index);
}
```

The more is done, now provide by yourself "undo" functionality.

## Update + rollBack

In **[this version](http://jsfiddle.net/fmusV/28/)** you have a rollBack functionality, but it quite bugged (don't work in some case).
Improve it!

## Update + rollBack fixed && working

Just for personal ego, **[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/fmusV/30/)** working rollBack. (cool!)

Comment: yea ..it works..u r awsome..can u helpme to rollback only on selected div(when clicking close button),and merge only rectangle. any way iam accepting tis answer.because this is more than enough for my question.